# Unable to execute kill function VBA - Run-time error '13'

Tags: excel, vba

I'm unable to perform the Kill function using Visual Basic in Excel. When I run the code to Kill, I get

> "Run-time error '13' Type mismatch'

Does anybody have any ideas? I've tried

```
Kill("pathname")
```

and

```
Kill "pathname"
```

I've tried different filetypes in various locations and always end up getting the same error.

Edit-  I've now reverted to attempting the simplest of Macros and I still get the error instantly:

```
Sub KillFile()
    Dim filetokill As String
    filetokill = "C:\Users\thomas.bennett\Desktop\test.txt"
    VBA.Kill filetokill
End Sub
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't like using the `Kill` command but just to clarify, is `pathname` a variable that holds the file name? If so, try `Kill(pathname)`

Comment: is pathname a variable, or are you actually writing a path in your code?

Comment: I have tried both. I have assigned a String variable with the path name and tried to Kill this. I have also attempted to enter the path name directly in the Kill function. It should also be noted that I've attempted to copy working code from online forums and I still get the same error message doing that.

Comment: Try `VBA.Kill`. Sounds like you have a naming conflict somewhere in your code. Does `VBA.Kill` raise the same error?

Comment: This also doesn't work. I've not reverted to running the simplest macro possible

Comment: Are you sure the error is coming from the `Kill` line?

Comment: And what do you mean by "instantly" -- are you stepping through the procedure using F8 key in the VBE debugger to see exactly what line is raising the error? Or when the error raises, enter Debug mode and see which line offends?

Comment: Sounds stupid, but try rebooting, opening a new instance of Excel with only a blank workbook, and execute the `Kill` statement from the Immediate pane in VBE. If that doesn't work, try repairing your install of Excel, because this error strictly should never happen!

Comment: Also curious, when you type `Kill ` in the VBE, what does intellisense give you as the argument/hint? http://imgur.com/a/RDvEw

Comment: I get the exact same as you do

Comment: Try rebooting :)  Then try repairing Excel ... that's all I got. Nothing about this code should fail in this context.

Comment: I've just tried the same thing on a co-workers PC and got exactly the same result. Could it be something to do with permissions do you think?

Comment: Is this literally all the code in your workbook?

Comment: This is literally the only thing in there, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Both of these should work, to delete a file from for instance, your desktop.

```
Sub killfile1()

Dim filetokill As String
filetokill = "C:\Users\yourusername\Desktop\test.txt"
Kill filetokill

End Sub
```

---

```
Sub killfile2()

Kill "C:\Users\yourusername\Desktop\test.txt"

End Sub
```

---

I've had an idea though.. you haven't created a FUNCTION or SUB called `Kill` have you? I just created one and it didn't disallow it:

```
Function kill(filename As Integer)

End Function
```

If this is present, I get the exact same error (13) as you when running either of my example macros. Check your code for other uses of `Kill`.

Comment: I've tried both of these with no success. The same error keeps appearing.

Comment: I'm now running this code in a brand new worksheet to help with finding the cause but it still arises even in a new workbook

Comment: I thought about the naming error but OP indicates that even explicitly calling `VBA.Kill` raises the same error...

Comment: I'm gobsmacked, @DavidZemens. I didn't know you could essentially overwrite commands like this. I've just created the following: `Function chr(f): chr = "E": End Function` which will now completely break any use of the standard `Chr` function.

Comment: @CLR yep, if you do that, you have to explicitly call `VBA.Chr`, etc. :)

Comment: Screenshots uploaded :)